# Count distinct strings in rolling window using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I count the number of unique strings in a rolling window of a pandas dataframe?

```
a = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','a','a','b','c','d','e','e','e','e'])
a.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)))
```

Output, same as original dataframe:

```
    0
0   a
1   b
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   c
6   d
7   e
8   e
9   e
10  e
```

Expected:

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   2
9   1
10  1
```

Comment: Would you always be working with a rolling window of size `3`?

Comment: No, that is just as a simple example. In my real use case, I have a timestamp index which uses a timedelta for the window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need first convert values to numeric - by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) or by [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html). Also `min_periods` parameter is necessary for avoid `NaN` in start of column:

```
a[0] = pd.factorize(a[0])[0]
print (a)
    0
0   0
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   4
8   4
9   4
10  4

b = a.rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x))).astype(int)
print (b)
    0
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   2
9   1
10  1
```

Or:

```
a[0] = a[0].rank(method='dense')
      0
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   2.0
5   3.0
6   4.0
7   5.0
8   5.0
9   5.0
10  5.0

b = a.rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x))).astype(int)
print (b)
    0
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   2
9   1
10  1
```

Comment: this looks good, do you know if either has better performance over a very large dataframe?

Comment: I think first - factorize  ;)

Comment: Curious as to why just `lambda x: len(np.unique(x))` doesn't work.  Off the bat, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.  That's a perflectly valid operation and works on `a` as a whole.

Comment: @JohnGalt - why does not work non numeric - I think it is not implemnted yet or bug.

Comment: great idea to use `factorize()`.